# ko.toJSON is creating some unwanted copiedProperties properties

Tags: knockout.js

I'm findign that ko.toJSON is creating some unwanted stuff like:

copiedProperties
destroy

```
{"test":1,"AppStart":true,"requestedDateFormat":"YYYY-MM-DD","__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"test":true,"AppStart":true,"requestedDateFormat":true},"copiedProperties":{}}}
```

whats the point of these? can I remove them by default?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using the [KO mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) you should use the plugin's conversion methods e.g.

```
ko.mapping.toJSON
```

and
    ko.mapping.toJS

instead of the built in `ko.toJSON` and `ko.toJS`.

Because the mapping version of the methods will take of the additional properties which by the way are used internally by the plugin itself.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/UByft/13/).

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me: in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project, my ViewModel contained loads of form fields, and a very large SelectList, which I mapped to a Knockout ViewModel on the client using `ko.mapping.fromJSON()`.  I tried (unsuccessfully) deleting the SelectList data from the ViewModel, and then using `ko.toJSON()` to serialize the form data and send it back up, but the ViewModel contained all of the `mappedProperties` of that huge SelectList, which made the JSON too big for the server to handle. Using `ko.mapping.toJSON()` fixed the problem.  Thanks much!

Comment: An important difference that i have recently encountered is that the mapping equivalents will not convert any existing observables that were not mapped / updated after the mapper was used. See: https://jsbin.com/jupemoneri/6/edit?js,console

Answer (score 4):

If your model is a 'hybrid' model that hasn't completely been created using the mapping plugin then using `ko.mapping.toJSON` may not remove the `__ko_mapping__` properties you're expecting.

By 'hybrid' model I mean one you've created as a normal object and then mapped only portions into it with the mapping plugin.

The easiest solution is to add the following to each 'class' that is ending up with the unwanted properties. This will remove it whether you use `mapping.toJSON` or `ko.toJSON`.

```
    Product.prototype.toJSON = function()
    {
        var copy = ko.toJS(this);

        delete (copy.__ko_mapping__);

        return copy;
    }
```

This method is described in [Controlling How an Object Is Converted to JSON](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html) although not in connection to the mapping plugin.

---

#### Example:

Here's some JSON that ended up with unwanted mapping when it was serialized (even with `ko.mapping.toJSON`).

I just added the above code to the 'product' class (I'm using typescript so I'm calling them classes).

> {"sku":"3007","total":0,"desc":"Description","qty":0,"each":null,"dirty":false,"removePending":false,"editableQty":0,"itemUpdating":false,"**__ko_mapping__**":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"sku":true,"qty":true},"copiedProperties":{}}},{"sku":"3008","total":0,"desc":"Description","qty":0,"each":null,"dirty":false,"removePending":false,"editableQty":0,"itemUpdating":false,"**__ko_mapping__**":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"sku":true,"qty":true},"copiedProperties":{}}},

Afterwards I got this much cleaner JSON. I'm now going to go back and `delete(copy.removePending)` and `delete(copy.itemUpdating)` which are view model only.

> {"sku":"3007","total":0,"desc":"Description","qty":0,"each":null,"dirty":false,"removePending":false,"editableQty":0,"itemUpdating":false},{"sku":"3008","total":0,"desc":"Description","qty":0,"each":null,"dirty":false,"removePending":false,"editableQty":0,"itemUpdating":false},

---

Also please note that calling the mapping version of `toJSON` internally just calls `JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(object))`. In other words `ko.mapping.toJSON` is a convenience function and does not do its own stringification.

```
// from mapping source code
exports.toJSON = function (rootObject, options)
{
    var plainJavaScriptObject = exports.toJS(rootObject, options);
    return ko.utils.stringifyJson(plainJavaScriptObject);
};

// from main knockout source code for `ko.utils`
stringifyJson: function (data, replacer, space) {   // replacer and space are optional
    if (!JSON || !JSON.stringify)
        throw new Error("Cannot find JSON.stringify(). Some browsers (e.g., IE < 8) don't support it natively, but you can overcome this by adding a script reference to json2.js, downloadable from http://www.json.org/json2.js");
    return JSON.stringify(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data), replacer, space);
},
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem I'm having. Why doesn't ko.mapping.toJS() remove the __ko_mapping__ function?